# Tenant Identitification in UserInfo endpoint for IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

My client application passes back the tenant name on auth redirect using ACR_VALUES and I can use in my implementation of AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator to handle Tenant specific login/consent related code.  After the auth callback, my client uses the UserInfo endpoint to get claims about the user and one of the things my IProfileService needs to know is the tenant to check certain claims.  I haven't been able to find a way to indicate the Tenant to the UserInfo endpoint and the context.Subject at that point does not have the claims issues earlier in the login process.  I did notice the Token endpoint has will look at ACR_VALUES, but when I make those calls the context.Subject is based on the logged in User so the claim exists from earlier, but no claims come back in that token.

Is there something I am missing in being able to determine the Tenant during a call to UserInfo in an implementation of IProfileService?

Answer (score 0):

After a couple hours searching for a proper extensibility option within IdentityServer4, here is what I ended up with.  The default UserInfo endpoint does not look at ACR values and I didn't want to build my own endpoint implementation, so I appended a header to the client during my call in :

```
IHttpClientFactory factory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = factory.CreateClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Tenant", tenant.ShortName);
UserInfoResponse userInfoResponse = await client.GetUserInfoAsync(new UserInfoRequest
{
    Address = doc.UserInfoEndpoint,
    Token = tokenResponse.AccessToken
});
```

To access this value in my IProfileService, I inject the IHttpContextAccessor service and can pull the header value off in GetProfileDataAsync:

```
 string tenantName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Tenant"].SingleOrDefault();
```

Hopefully this is helpful to someone else looking to implement tenant specific claims checks.